# Why we take arbitrary current directions for same circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Can anyone tell me why V2 and V3 are negative. I mean while writing KVL equation if we take current to be flowing in clockwise direction then why

> > V2=+2x5

If current flows in clockwise direction(as in KVL equations) then we should write V2=-2x5 according to **PSC.** 
[image]

Comment: In your circuit, the 5mA current source will determine the current direction. So in your circuit, the current will flow in anticlockwise direction thanks to the current source. So if you assume clockwise direction you must flip the voltage polarities across the resistors only.  10V = I*2 + I*6 + V1 and I = -5mA (the minus sign because I current is flowing in opposite direction then 5mA current) and if you solve this you will get V1 = 50V

Comment: And voltage polarity across resistor must always "follow" the current directions that we have chosen at the beginning of our analysis.

Comment: Why not? If when you solve the resulting equations you get negative answers then youu initial assumption was wrong so you just reverse the directions

Answer (score 1):

You can take arbitrary current directions but, take care. If you don't track this change everywhere in your circuit, you'll get a negative sign where there shouldn't be one, and the wrong answer (wrong circuit model).

Do an experiment, take the same circuit and draw the currents in one direction and work out the equations. Then take the same circuit and draw all the currents in the opposite directions from the first diagram and work out the equations. The thing you'll notice is that you essentially multiplied the current by -1 inverting the direction. If you take all the equations and multiply them by -1 on both sides (or any constant) you'll get the same answer.

Thus it doesn't matter which direction you take the current to be in, but it does matter that you track the direction correctly when you work out the equations.

Comment: If we take current in clockwise direction, V2=-ve(following +ve sign convention) and also the V6=-ve, and answer i.e. V1 won't remain 50 in that case.